# Is there an open high frequency (1-0.2 Hz) wind measurement dataset from a marine station?

Tags: meteorology, wind, open-data, database

I want to conduct a statistical analysis of high-frequency wind measurements. This analysis aims to define relevant parameters for competitive coastal sailboat racing so the sampling frequency should be exceptionally high (in the order of 1-0.2 Hz). Could someone please help me find such a dataset open to the public?

Answer (score 2):

One possible source could be the FINO stations in the North and Baltic Sea. I am not sure on how high the frequency is (couldn't find any information on the website). But I am quite sure that ultra sonic anemometers are used so the measurement frequency should be good enough for you.

I suppose you have to register for the data, but I think it is free to use.

https://www.fino-offshore.de/en/index.html